# MS Access query, IIF function is returning error as "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have Access query which does Union, group, get Maximum, Left Join and IIF(isNull) functions. 
[image]
I have to union three subTables and group by column "mainid", get max-value from column "time" as "MaxSubTime" and mainid-column is filterd by mainTable.id.
Then I am applying LEFT Join MainTable to Union-Group.
If MaxSubTime is Null then i am applying the MainTable.endtime to MaxSubTime and getting it as "MaxMainTableEndTime".
till here everything works fine.

```
string myQry = "SELECT MainTable.id, MainTable.sttime, IIF(IsNULL(a.MaxSubTime), MainTable.endtime, a.MaxSubTime) AS MaxMainTableEndTime 
            FROM (MainTable LEFT JOIN (SELECT mainid, MAX(SubTime) AS MaxSubTime 
            FROM (SELECT Sub_table_1.mainid, Sub_table_1.time AS SubTime FROM Sub_table_1 
                  UNION SELECT Sub_table_2.mainid, Sub_table_2.time AS SubTime Sub_table_2 
                  UNION SELECT Sub_table_3.mainid, Sub_table_3.time AS SubTime Sub_table_3 GROUP BY mainid) AS a ON a.mainid = MainTable.id)                       
            WHERE MaxMainTableEndTime >= #" + DateTime.Now + "# ";
```

But when i filter the final query by "MaxMainTableEndTime", i am getting this error "No value given for one or more required parameters".
Where i am doing mystake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me solved this issue by using "Having" clause and editing my code a little

```
string myQry = "SELECT MainTable.id, MainTable.sttime, a.MaxSubTime
FROM MainTable LEFT JOIN (SELECT mainid, MAX(SubTime) AS MaxSubTime
FROM(SELECT Sub_table_1.mainid, Sub_table_1.time AS SubTime FROM Sub_table_1 
UNION SELECT Sub_table_2.mainid, Sub_table_2.time AS SubTime Sub_table_2
UNION SELECT Sub_table_3.mainid, Sub_table_3.time AS SubTime Sub_table_3 
GROUP BY mainid HAVING MaxSubTime >= #" + DateTime.Now + "#)
AS a ON a.mainid = MainTable.id) WHERE MainTable.endtime >= #" + DateTime.Now + "# "
```